# Sum of All the Others

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

There are ten different 10-digit decimal fractions, one of them being equal to the sum of the other nine. If each number has 10 unique digits, not counting the 0 before the decimal point  (for example  $.9876543210$), what is the least possible value for the one which is the sum of the others?

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding this "*one that is equals the sum of all the other decimal numbers*" - do you mean that, among the ten numbers, one of them equals the sum of the other nine? By "*decimal number*", do you mean a large number (several billion) expressed in base 10, or a small number (between 0 and 1) expressed as a decimal fraction?

Comment: @Rand al'thor  -right one of them is the sum of the other nine and these decimal numbers are less than 1.

Comment: lets ignore the zero before the decimal point

Comment: Are you taking the sum *modulo 1* (i.e. ignoring everything before the decimal point), or is the sum of those nine 10-digit numbers directly equal to the tenth one?

Comment: ..the 10th or the sum of other nine is also less than 1

Comment: It might be simpler to think of them as 10-digit integers _that are allowed to have leading zeros_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 1203456789 (if interpreting as 10-digit integers which can start with zero).

Reasoning

> Since each of the numbers is not less than 0123456789, so the sum of the 9 is not less than 123456789*9=1111111101. The smallest number which is not less than 1111111101 and contains all digits is 1203456789. The following set of numbers, for example:
>  a=0124635789
>  b=0123456789
>  c=0123756489
>  d=0123457689
>  e=0123546789
>  f=0182345679
>  g=0152364789
>  h=0126435789
>  i=0123456987
>  sums up to 1203456789. (This set was found without a computer, roughly with writing down all 123456789's and the remaining part to the desired sum, then swapping the digits which give equal sums to make all numbers different.)